# Is this nested loop the fastest option for performing this task?

Tags: java, arraylist, nested

The first part of the code creates a random arrayList. 
Method 1 is the "traditional" approach for a nested loop.
Method 2 removes elements not found from arrayList2Temp in order to save one comparison on the next iteration. In theory the later approach should be faster, however it is not. I build a stopwatch into the code so it outputs the time in milliseconds needed to perform each method. The last part is a consistency check to make sure that the each method does indeed create the same result. Should I be using nested arrayLists at all? What would be the correct way to perform this task in parallel i.e. without having to iterate through each element? In any case would I be happy for any suggestion which would be able to cut down a few milliseconds.

Delete4

```
    package delete4;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

    /**
    *
    * @author
    */
    public class Delete4 {

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //create random arrayList
            Random rand = new Random();
            int Recipient = 0;
            int list0ItemCount = 5000;
            int Score = 0;
            ArrayList<Class1> arrayList0 = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list0ItemCount; i++) {
                Recipient = rand.nextInt((100000 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                while (Recipient == i) {
                    Recipient = rand.nextInt((100000 - 1) + 1) + 1;
                }
                Score = rand.nextInt((10 + 10) + 1) - 10;
                arrayList0.add(new Class1(i, Recipient, Score, Score));
            }
            double startTime;
            double endTime;
            double duration = 0;
            //method 1
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            ArrayList<Class1> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<>(arrayList0);
            ArrayList<Class1> arrayList1Temp = new ArrayList<>(arrayList0);
            int list1ItemCount = arrayList1.size();
            int list1TempItemCount = arrayList1.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < list1ItemCount; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < list1TempItemCount; j++) {
                    if (arrayList1.get(i).Recipient == arrayList1Temp.get(j).Recipient && arrayList1.get(i).ID != arrayList1Temp.get(j).ID) {
                        arrayList1.set(i, new Class1(arrayList1.get(i).ID, arrayList1.get(i).Recipient, arrayList1.get(i).Score, arrayList1.get(i).CumulativeScore + arrayList1Temp.get(j).Score));
                    }
                }
            }
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
            System.out.println(duration);
            //method 2
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            ArrayList<Class1> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>(arrayList0);
            ArrayList<Class1> arrayList2Temp = new ArrayList<>(arrayList0);
            int list2ItemCount = arrayList2.size();
            int list2TempItemCount = arrayList2Temp.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < list2ItemCount; i++) {
                boolean found = false;
                int k = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < list2TempItemCount; j++) {
                    if (arrayList2.get(i).Recipient == arrayList2Temp.get(j).Recipient && arrayList2.get(i).ID != arrayList2Temp.get(j).ID) {
                        arrayList2.set(i, new Class1(arrayList2.get(i).ID, arrayList2.get(i).Recipient, arrayList2.get(i).Score, arrayList2.get(i).CumulativeScore + arrayList2Temp.get(j).Score));
                        found = true;
                    }
                    if (arrayList2.get(i).Recipient == arrayList2Temp.get(j).Recipient && arrayList2.get(i).ID == arrayList2Temp.get(j).ID) {
                        k = j;
                    }
                }
                if (found == false) {
                    arrayList2Temp.remove(k);
                    list2TempItemCount = arrayList2Temp.size();
                }
            }
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000;
            System.out.println(duration);
            //consistency check
            for (int i = 0; i < list0ItemCount; i++) {
                if (arrayList2.get(i).ID != arrayList1.get(i).ID ||
                    arrayList2.get(i).Recipient != arrayList1.get(i).Recipient ||
                    arrayList2.get(i).Score != arrayList1.get(i).Score ||
                    arrayList2.get(i).CumulativeScore != arrayList1.get(i).CumulativeScore) {
                    System.out.println("error1");
                }
            } 
        }

    }
```

Class1

```
    package delete4;

    /**
     *
     * @author
     */
    public class Class1 {
        int ID;
        int Recipient;
        int Score;
        int CumulativeScore;
        Class1(int ID, int Recipient, int Score, int CumulativeScore) {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.Recipient = Recipient;
            this.Score = Score;
            this.CumulativeScore = CumulativeScore;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hint: you want to read about java naming conventions; variable names never start with upper case letters. Well, naming in general could be improved. Things should **say** what they are used for; so arrayList2 and arrayList2Temp are pretty nothing-saying names for example. And you might consult "Clean code" by Robert Martin; especially the "single layer of abstraction" principle would benefit to you ...

Comment: Using `System.nanoTime` isn't a particularly accurate way of benchmarking the performance of each method, consider using a Java Profiler to do that instead.

Comment: ok thx for the suggestions so far!

Comment: @JCD Am I right in thinking you want to remove elements where `ID` and `Recipient` are the same?

Comment: @arizzle method 2 is just an attempt to speed up method 1 (a simple nested loop) the idea is: basically I am just looking through arrayList2 for duplicate Recipients. However if I compare the arrayList2 with itself I might just create a temporary arrayList2Temp and remove a element which has no duplicate, except of course itself, to have a quicker iteration on the next pass.

Comment: @arizzle You may ignore method 2, it seems to be slower anyways (got to verify with your Java Profiler suggestion). It does produce the same result as method 1.